# Why were early satellites produced with polished "mirror-like" surfaces?

Tags: thermal, tracking, thermal-control, visibility-of-spacecraft

Many/most early artificial satellites were spheres with mirror-like polished outer surfaces.

I am guessing that for lower orbits the spherical shape minimized drag as well as simplified the analysis and interpretation of rate of decay, since this was critical to understand in the early days.

But the metal could have been roughened, anodized, or even painted, rather than having a mirror-like finish. Was this done for reasons of visibility and optical tracking? Or was it done for reasons of thermal management, where the emissivity in the visible determined heat absorption and in the IR determined radiation? Or another reason, or for no particular reason at all beyond aesthetics?

I'm looking for *an answer supported with a source that addresses the design intention at the time*.

Below [Sputnik-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sputnik_asm.jpg), [Luna-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RIAN_archive_510848_Interplanetary_station_Luna_1_-_blacked.jpg), and [Vanguard-1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vanguard_1.jpg).

[image: Sputnik-1] [image: Luna-1] [image: Vanguard-1]

---

Exploring the "aesthetics" angle, [rendering of Vanguard-1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vanguard_1_composite.jpg) versus [disco mirror ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Disco_ball4.jpg):

[image: rendering of Vanguard-1] [image: disco mirror ball]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [the official NASA history of Vanguard](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4202.pdf) it was for visibility and thermal control.

(Bolding mine)

> Tousey  had  made  some  of  the  first  calculations  in  the  fall 
>   of  1955,  contributing  his  knowledge  of  optics  **to  ensure 
>   that  protective  coatings  on  the  exterior  of  the  booster  and 
>   on  the  satellite  shell  would  have  sufficient  reflec­tivity  to
>   permit  telescopic  observation  of  the  course  of  the  rocket  as 
>   it  rose  and  then  optical  acquisition  and  tracking  of  the 
>   satellite  in  space.**   Schach  undertook  the  "thermal  design," 
>   that  is,  the  calculations  of  what  tempera­tures  to  expect  at
>   various  points  in  the  satellite's  orbit,  in  darkness  and  in 
>   daylight,  **the  selection  of  the  optimum  thickness  of  coating 
>   materials  to  emphasize  their  emissiveness  of  solar  heat 
>   radiation,**  and  methods  of  keeping  the  satellite's  surface  free
>   of  contaminating  substances  such  as  soot  which  would 
>   ultimately  raise  the  satellite's  temperature.  Hass  worked  out 
>   the  techniques  of  applying  the  successive  surface  coatings-the 
>   gold  plating,  the  chromium  evaporated  to  vapor  and  deposited 
>   to  serve  as  a  primer,  the  silicon  oxide  to  serve  as  a
>   barrier,  the  thin  layer  of  evaporated  aluminum  to  give  a 
>   mirror-like  finish,  and  finally  a  film  of  silicon  oxide  to 
>   control  emitted  radiation.  Drummeter  and  Schach  were  chiefly 
>   responsible  for  developing  the  sunlight  simulator  with  carbon 
>   arcs  as  the  source  of  high­ intensity  light.  Through  windows 
>   in  the  large  cylindrical  vacuum  tank  in  which  the  coated 
>   sphere  sat  for  two  or  three  days  of  testing,  the  simulated 
>   sunlight  beat  upon  the  satellite's  surface  and  indirectly 
>   heated  the  inner  pot  of  instruments.  Measurements  of  the 
>   effects  furnished  means  of  determining  the  most  desirable 
>   material  and  thickness  of  the  layering  required.  LaGow  acted 
>   as  advisor  and  monitor  on  all  these  operations.  Every  man 
>   concerned  with  temperature  control  worked  closely  with  every 
>   other.

Comment: Holy granola! I had no idea that the surfaces were so complex; this is really fascinating stuff! I'm guessing that the final SiO2 on top of the evaporated aluminum works the same way as the back-side aluminized glass mirrors work on modern spacecraft radiators as mentioned in [this insightful comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21524/#comment60250_21547).

Comment: The outer silicon oxide layer was deposited to protect the reflective coating.  The coatings were actually deposited by Alan Bradford who worked for Dr. Hass at the time.

Comment: @Vince49 so you believe the statement in the block quote "..and finally a film of silicon oxide to control emitted radiation." is wrong/false? Is that just a guess or can you source it? I'm thinking that it's possible at the time that spacecraft technology was considered somewhat sensitive, and the details may have been obfuscated. At the same time, a sputtered oxide layer may be too thin (physically, or optically) to behave the same way (from an emissive point of view) as those thick glass layers I've linked to.

Comment: Hi uhoh.  It's not a guess.  Some members of Dr. Hass's group later worked for me.

Comment: I was not able to complete the comment above due to the 5 minute edit rule.  

The coatings were made under the guidance of Dr. Hass, mostly at Ft. Belvoir, VA in an area that later became the Night Vision Laboratory.  The quoted passage is correct in general, but not in some details.  For example, the chromium layer is deposited _before_ the gold for adhesion.  Now days, usually titanium, rather than chromium, is deposited before a gold layer to improve adhesion.

Comment: @uhoh, I'm working to get you information on the original intent of the coatings.  One of the original players is still working part time and I just sent him an email.  Please check back in a few days.

Comment: Sounds like you should be able to post a very authoritative answer! Looking forward to it.

Comment: @Vince49 Oh, it's definitely common for Cr or Ti to be used as an adhesion layer before Au. While it's not mentioned first, the paragraph indicates it's used as a "primer" which could mean (to me at least) *before* the gold. So while the wording is imperfect, I think could still be consistent with the Cr being applied before the Au. Anyway, thanks for the input! This must have been a really exciting time! :-)

Comment: I too think is was an exciting time.  From what they told me later, I believe the fellows involved saw that work as their magnum opus.  And I would agree.  Vanguard was the second US satellite launched and the first ever solar powered satellite!